How to get Visual Studio 2010 product key
I found this
Any way to retrieve Visual Studio production key?
super useful, but I need something similar for Visual Studio 2010.
I have a licensed VS2010 on one W12 server and planning to transfer the software and the license on a newer server. I could not find a 1 2yr old email, so I have no way to retrieve my product key.
EDIT:
This whole subject had been moved to the back burner for a while and reemerged recently.
I managed to find the registry key @Ramhound mentioned
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\4D8CFBCB-2F6A-4AD2-BABF-10E28F6F2C8F
but this key has 19 subkeys. Which one is correct?
The subkeys are:
07060, 07062, 07063, 07064, 07065, 07066, 07067, 07068, 07069, 07070, 07071, 07072, 07073, 07074, 07075, 07076, 07077, 07078, 0bcad
Another detail I think may be worth citing: The version I currently have is Visual Studio 2010 Shell Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Nirsoft's ProduKey, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html, offered support for Visual Studio as of v. 1.65 . That said, some AV products consider it a "Potentially Unwanted Program" (PUP), though it has legitimate uses, as in your case.

The tool in the duplicate can be trivially modified to support VS2010. All you have to do is identify the UID for VS2010. It will be something like 4D8CFBCB-2F6A-4AD2-BABF-10E28F6F2C8F\07062 edit your question to include that vital information.

@Ramhound Precisely!! But i think that UID is related to a newer version of VS. I could not find the uid for VS10, do you know where i can search?

Which is the reason I asked for the UID for Visual Studio 2010.  I can't explain how to find it, only it's in the exact same location, as the other UID for different versions of Visual Studio. When you [edit] your question in order to provide enough information to answer your question it can be reopened.
